# Does $\lambda$-completion of $\kappa$-Boolean algebras preserve monomorphisms?

Tags: ct.category-theory, order-theory, boolean-algebras

Let $\kappa \le \lambda$ be infinite regular cardinals.  Does the free $\lambda$-completion functor $F_\kappa^\lambda$ from the category of $\kappa$-complete Boolean algebras to the category of $\lambda$-complete Boolean algebras preserve monomorphisms?  In other words, if $A \subseteq B$ is a sub-$\kappa$-complete Boolean algebra, is the canonical $\lambda$-homomorphism $F_\kappa^\lambda(A) \to F_\kappa^\lambda(B)$ injective?

(The answer is yes for $\kappa = \aleph_0$, by the following argument.  Let $C \subseteq F_{\aleph_0}^\lambda(B)$ be the sub-$\lambda$-algebra generated by the image of $A \to F_{\aleph_0}^\lambda(A) \to F_{\aleph_0}^\lambda(B)$.  Any homomorphism $f : A \to D$ extends to a homomorphism $f' : B \to \bar{D}$ where $\bar{D}$ is the MacNeille completion of $D$.  Then $f'$ induces a $\lambda$-homomorphism $f'' : F_{\aleph_0}^\lambda(B) \to \bar{D}$, whose restriction to $C$ extends $f$.  Thus $C \cong F_{\aleph_0}^\lambda(A)$.)

Comment: Is not $\overline{F_\kappa^\lambda(B)}\cong\bar B$ in general?

Comment: In fact - where do you use that $\kappa=\aleph_0$?

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე, I don't think that $\overline{F_\kappa^\lambda(B)} \cong \bar{B}$ in general - for fixed $B$ the former can be arbitrarily large, by Gaifman-Hales.  $\kappa = \aleph_0$ is used to extend $f$ to $f'$ (complete Boolean algebras are injective).

Comment: Yes, I agree, free completions can be much larger than MacNeille. Concerning $\aleph_0$ - I thought by $\aleph_0$-complete you meant countably complete...

Comment: ...no wait, why is your extension $f''|_C$ unique?

Comment: By $\kappa$-complete, I meant joins of $<\kappa$ elements.  The extension $f''|_C$ is unique because $C$ is generated by $A$ as a $\lambda$-complete algebra.